# It is possible to replace an inner join query by a containable in a habtm relationship?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, has-and-belongs-to-many, containable

I read the section  [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) and I didn't find a clear example to replace an inner join query on a habtm relationship by a *containable* query. Example :

**Model**

```
Student hasAndBelongsToMany Teacher
Teacher hasAndBelongsToMany Student
```

**Query**

```
$joins = array(
    array(
        'table' => 'teachers_students',
        'type' => 'INNER',
        'conditions' => array(
            'teachers_students.teacher_id' => $teacherId,
            'teachers_students.student_id = Student.id'
        )
    )
);

$data = $this->find('all', array('joins' => $joins));
```

**Comments**

- The `hasAndBelongsToMany` attributes are set in each model.
- pseudo-variable `$this` reference to model : `class Student`
- `$teacherId` is a parameter (there is a filter to show students that belong to one specific teacher).

**What I'm looking for**

To be able to write the same query without `joins`, using `contain`.  Something like :

```
$contain = array(
    'Teacher' => array(
        'conditions' => array('???' => '???')
    )
);    

$data = $this->find('all', array('contain' => $contain));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question (trying to get the students for a specific teacher), you'll either need to A)  Use Joins, or B) switch the direction of your query and build it from the Teacher model instead:

```
//Teacher Model
$this->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('Teacher.id' => $teacherId),
    'contain' => array(
        'Student'
    )
);
```

You cannot limit the results of the main-model based on conditions against contained models because using "contain" actually creates separate queries.